# Necessary and sufficient conditions for countably additive probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have been struggling with understanding the solution to the exercise that follows. I cannot grasp why one of the conditions is that $x+y+z=2$. How do they come up with the value 2?

Exercise:

Suppose $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and $F$ is the collection of all subsets of Ω. Find (with proof) necessary and sufficient conditions on the real numbers x, y and z such that there exists a countably additive probability measure $\mathbb P$ on $F$, with $x = P\{1,2\}$, $y = P\{2,3\}$ and $z = \{1,2,3\}$.

Solution. The necessary and sufficient conditions are: $0≤x≤1$, $0≤y≤1$, $0≤z≤1$, and **$x+y+z=2$**

Comment: Did you mean to type "z=P{1,3}"?

Comment: Yes @Henry that´s what I meant to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: a countably additive probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $F$ is one that is just plain old finitely additive. In particular, it is finitely additive on the singletons (because $F$ contains all three singletons).

Also, how many times does each element appear in your sets relating to $x$,$y$, and $z$?

Comment: That would be 2 times @Andrew

Comment: Exactly. And $2 \times \mathbb{P}(\Omega)$ = 2(1) = 2.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much @Andrew! :)